# How to encode r_hash to check payment invoice using LND REST API

Tags: base64, hex

I am trying to use LND to create an invoice and then check it. This is quite easy using the command line, but I'm stuck on the encoding of the r_hash in the HTTP API. Docs can be found [here](https://api.lightning.community/?shell#v1-invoice).

If I create an invoice using:

```
curl -X POST 'https://localhost:8080/v1/invoices' -k -H 'Grpc-metadata-macaroon: my-macaroon'
```

I get something along the lines of

```
{
  "r_hash":"ud8NgqDTgCUri3sqb8D85YaRsnCtnQzY56iLwGWUXA4=",
  "payment_request":"lnbc1ps5xjcxpp5h80smq4q6wqz22ut0v4xls8uukrfrvns4kwsek884z9uqev5ts8qdqqcqzpgxqyz5vqsp5c0sxrfllt0hste83mevptfyvgcf9csg05rg8326vvhl9a0mfm73s9qyyssqgcehn536edaxhjpycu4hedl9klkqtkknnng653fdfqxxwpcdncus7gkmtxy9wpeezw9tupwh4nunpt9f0yg233233xgs0c2qpnlqe4sq7jlqxp",
  "add_index":"61",
  "payment_addr":"w+Bhp/9b7wXk8d5YFaSMRhJcQQ+g0HirTGX+Xr9p36M="
}
```

The r_hash here is different from what the cli gives me when I look up the invoice: `b9df0d82a0d380252b8b7b2a6fc0fce58691b270ad9d0cd8e7a88bc065945c0e`.

My problem is I don't know how to convert between the two. I've tried hex and base64. The docs say the r_hash `must be encoded as base64.`

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The API was returning the hash base64 encoded, and I was able to get the API to accept it hex encoded. This required decoding and re-encoding:

```
import codecs, base64

codecs.encode(base64.b64decode(h.encode('utf-8')), 'hex')
```